# CSS issue with inline-block and list-style-image

Tags: css

Any idea why when I apply `display: inline-block` to an list element, the list-style-image stops appearing?

Comment: Because inline blocks aren't list items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most important style property for a list item is that its `display` defaults to `list-item`. That setting is the reason why the element gets displayed with the respective `list-style`. Setting `display` to `inline-block` removes the only thing about your list item that makes it a list item.

Comment: I see, but I have a big list, and i want to split it in two cols, so inline-block looks the more logical.

Comment: There are many ways you can split a list into columns, though none of them are really all that elegant. Here's a good article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

Comment: Thanks. As you said non of them are really elegant and not flexible at all when the amount of elements is unknown, except maybe the old good "float".

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list element to use inline-block but still show bullets, you can use the ::before pseudo element and the content property:

```
li {
 display: inline-block;
}
li::before {
 content: '\25cf\a0';
}
```

( \25cf is the Unicode filled circle symbol and \a0 is a non-breaking space ).

Answer (score 1):

You can use float:left;  on your li element and add a min-width and min-height

```
.footer ul li{
    float: left;
    list-style-image: url(../images/arrow.png);
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 38px;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```